# pgsql - convert epoch timestamp from mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is there a better way to convert epoch timestamp function from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

The data structure of column `time` that I used is `INT(11)`.

In MySQL, we can use:
`YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))`

In PostgreSQL, we can use:
`TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(time), 'YYYY')`

However, it returns an error when we try to use it with `GROUP BY`.

`PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  column "table.time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the conversions functions - `TO_TIMESTAMP` or `TO_CHAR`. Unlike MySQL, in a `GROUP BY` query, PostgreSQL doesn't allow you to use a column  not part of `group by` plainly in select part, without an aggregate function

Comment: @KaushikNayak also don't pas invalid/old information, since MySQL 5.7 [GROUP BY handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY alot has changed..

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)